# html master page with data base sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net

plss help i have this problem:

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

this is the master page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon/x-icon" href="Main Images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyStyle.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('Main Images/background.jpg');">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div dir="rtl" style="background-color:#242020">
        <audio src="songs/Jurassic Park Theme Song - Jurassic Park Theme Song.mp3" autoplay="" controls=""></audio><br /><br />
    </div>
        <div class="top">
             <center><a href="index.aspx"> <img src="Main Images/logo.png" /></a></center>
            <div>
                   <form name="login">
            <span style="margin-top:25px;color:goldenrod;margin-left:3%;">Username<span style="margin-left:7px"><asp:TextBox type="text" id="userid" name="userid" style="color:fuchsia" placeholder="User Name" class="gg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></span></span><br /><br />
            <span style="margin-top:25px;color:goldenrod;margin-left:3%">Password<span style="margin-left:7px"><asp:TextBox class="gg" type="password" id="pswrd" name="pswrd" style="color:goldenrod" placeholder="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /></span></span><p runat="server" id="ans" style="color:red"></p>      
             <span style="margin-left:4%"><asp:Button ID="Button1" onclick="Check_Click"  class="login" runat="server" Text="Login" />
            <input type="reset" class="cencel" value="Cancel"/></span><br /><br /><span style="margin-left:4.7%"><a class="button" href="Had Sign Up.aspx">sign up to HaD</a></span>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check(form) { 
                if(form.userid.value == "Oz Cohen" && form.pswrd.value == "guzguz8") {
                    window.open('HaDMan.aspx');
                }
                else {
                    if (form.userid.value != "Oz Cohen" && form.pswrd.value!= "guzguz8") { document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = ("Eror Username and Password") }
                    if (form.userid.value == "Oz Cohen" && form.pswrd.value != "guzguz8") { document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = ("Eror Password") }
                    if (form.userid.value != "Oz Cohen" && form.pswrd.value == "guzguz8") { document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = ("Eror Username") }
                }
            }          
        </script>
            </div>
               <center>

                 <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" style="margin-top:7px">
                   <asp:TableRow>
                       <asp:TableCell> <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img style="margin-top:-20px"width="60" src="Main Images/lines.png" /></a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="opening page.aspx">My site page</a></li>
                    <li><a title="Got lost? Click here for the site map..." href="sitemap.aspx">Map of the site</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dinosuars videos.aspx">Dinosuars Movies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="new dino.aspx">Add new Dinosuars species</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Warning.aspx">Had Site</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
    <nav class="menu" >
     <ul>
         <li><span class="mainmenu"><a href="index.aspx">Home page</a></span></li>
     </ul>
     </nav>           
    </asp:TableCell>
     <asp:TableCell>
    <nav class="menu" >
     <ul>
         <li><span class="mainmenu"><a href="prdetors.aspx">Carnivores</a></span></li>
     </ul>
     </nav>           
    </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
    <nav class="menu" >
     <ul>
         <li><span class="mainmenu"><a href="Vegetarian.aspx">Vegetarian</a></span></li>
     </ul>
     </nav>           
    </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
        </div>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class DinoMenu : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection c;
        string str = "Data Source =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
        str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DinoData.mdf;";
        str += "Integrated Security= True";
        c = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE Pasword LIKE @Pasword AND Username LIKE @username;", c);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pasword", pswrd.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userid.Text);
        c.Open();
        int Userexist = (int)Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        c.Close();
        if (Userexist > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("HaD.aspx", true);
        }
        else
        {
            ans.InnerText = "Eror Username and Password";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put in your web.config the line: `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` ?

Comment: yes i did it did error

Comment: Yes I know I wrote it before I saw the nested forms in the code. Most of the times it should be the first thing to check but not in this case

Comment: why not at this case?

Comment: This error is a general error. The server was having troubles with your request so it says what he _thinks_ that might be the origin of your problem. In the message he wrote that you should try to add the `enableEventValidation` to your web.config.
Most of the times the server is right and this would have solved your problem, but not in your case because your problem was that you had two nested `forms` in your code and this only can be solved by deleting one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because of this line:

```
<form name="login">
```

**Delete this line** and you will be ok.

If you have to gather the elements of your login form together, change it to a `div` instead

### Explanation

**HTML** files **cannot contain** nested forms.

**Every .aspx/.master file is already a form** (That's the origin for the name Web Forms).

When you put a `<form>` inside one of these files you actually put your new form inside .NET's auto-created form